# What is the TypeScript type of an enum

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering what is the type of an enum? In my example I need to reference my `Direction` enum in my template. I am doing this by assigning the `Direction` enum to the `direction` variable I have exposed in my component. This variable is currently type `any` but I want to be more specific. What should this type be?

```
<!-- component.html -->
<p [ngSwitch="getDirection()"]>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="direction.NORTH">Heading North</span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="direction.EAST">Heading East</span>
</p>


// component.ts
enum Direction {
  NORTH,
  EAST,
  SOUTH,
  WEST
}
direction: any; // <-- what should this type be?
constructor() {
  this.direction = Direction;
}
```

Comment: `direction$: Direction`. Don't make it harder than it needs to be :).

Comment: I tried this but `this.direction$` gets highlighted with the error `Type 'typeof Direction' is not assignable to type 'Direction'`

Comment: Note the $ suffix is generally used to indicate an *observable*.

Comment: Yeah, you can't assign a type to a property expecting an instance. That line would have to be `this.direction$ = Direction.NORTH;` (or any of the enumerations)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Woops, did not realize that. I will adjust my code.

Comment: `direction$: typeof Direction;` should be ok

Comment: @TomaszGawel - awesome, `typeof Direction` did the trick. Can you reply with an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
direction$: typeof Direction;
```

Should be ok.

But actually you do not need this.
You may let typescript to infer this type:

```
enum Direction { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST }

class MyComponent {
  readonly direction$ = Direction;
  constructor() {
    //...
  }
}
```

There is no need to wait with initialization until constructor is called in this case, as everything is known in advance.

Now, you may hover direction$ field and see it's inferred type (I assume you are using vscode).